# Mapping System.Drawing.Color

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

If I don't map `Color` but map an object that has a Color attribute, `FluentNHibernate` successfully maps it to a `varbinary(max)`.  However, that's extremely inefficient given that realistically `Color` is just composed of 4 bytes and I am keen on improving it without using a new type to Proxy it.

Internally within `Color` it is made up of four properties,

1. `long value` (cast down to `int` to represent ARGB)
2. `short state`, indicates if this is a known & valid colour
3. `string name`, the name of the colour if known.
4. `short knownColor` a value to indicate which known colour it is

So I have attempted to map this as follows.

```
public ColorMapping()
{
    CompositeId()
        .KeyProperty(c => Reveal.Member<Color, long>("value"))
        .KeyProperty(c => Reveal.Member<Color, short>("state"))
        .KeyProperty(c => Reveal.Member<Color, string>("name"))
        .KeyProperty(c => Reveal.Member<Color, short>("knownColor"));
}
```

However, on usage I get the following exception,

> Class Initialization method DataContextTest.ClassInitialise threw
>   exception. FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException:
>   FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException: An invalid or
>   incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory.
>   Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.
>
> ---> FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException: An invalid or
>   incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory.
>   Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.
>
> ---> NHibernate.MappingException: Could not compile the mapping
>   document: (XmlDocument) ---> NHibernate.MappingException: Could not
>   determine type for:
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[[System.Func`2[[System.Drawing.Color,
>   System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a],[System.Int64, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]],
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, for columns:
>   NHibernate.Mapping.Column(Member).

Am I misusing `Reveal`?  If so, how am I meant to use it?

Comment: What is the contents of PotentialReasons? You may need to load the [assembly first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520758/fluent-nhibernate-mapping-entities-from-multiple-assemblies).

Comment: @Sebazzz `PotentialReasons Count = 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would map it as UserType which converts it back and forth

```
// in mapping
Map(x => x.Color).Column("ColorARGB").CustomType<ColorUserType>();

[Serializable]
class ColorUserType : IUserType
{
    public object Assemble(object cached, object owner)
    {
        return DeepCopy(cached);
    }

    public object DeepCopy(object value)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object Disassemble(object value)
    {
        return DeepCopy(value);
    }

    bool IUserType.Equals(object x, object y)
    {
        var colorX = x as Color;
        var colorY = y as Color;
        return colorX == null ? colorY = null : colorX.ToArgb() == colorY.ToArgb();
    }

    public virtual int GetHashCode(object x)
    {
        var colorX = (Color)x;
        return (colorX != null) ? colorX.ToArgb() : 0;
    }

    public bool IsMutable { get { return false; } }

    public object NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, string[] names, object owner)
    {
        return Color.FromArgb((int)NHibernateUtil.Int32.Get(rs, names[0]));
    }

    public void NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, object value, int index)
    {
        NHibernateUtil.Int32.Set(cmd, ((Color)value).ToArgb(), index);
    }

    public object Replace(object original, object target, object owner)
    {
        return original;
    }

    public Type ReturnedType { get { return typeof(Color); } }

    public SqlType[] SqlTypes { get { return new []{ SqlTypeFactory.Int32 }; } }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't save enough information.  FromRGB creates a Color object from the ARGB components.  The resulting object is different from the known Colors.  e.g. `Assert.AreEqual(Color.Blue, Color.FromArgb(-16776961))` will result in an `Exception`.  (The value is ARGB 255, 0, 0, 255)

Comment: then just change the equals method to use the ToArgb() value for equality

Comment: Is there a way to have an IUserType create two columns?  One for ARGB value, one for KnownColor?  Or do I need to shove the two values into an Int64 with shifting?

Comment: just like you did in your code only that IUserType is easier to implement than ICompositeUserType

Comment: Thanks for your help :)  I quite like the fact ICompositeUserType specifies its own column names so will probably stick with that.  Its shocking how often that code gets called when I stepped through it.  Probably going to go through it and implement it a lot more efficiently later on.

Comment: ICompositeUserType **does not** specify the column names in any way. They are always specified in the mapping. You specify the Property names of the Composite (Component) which is mapped to several columns

Comment: That's **not** true, `PropertyNames` is certainly used to specify the column names.  (At least the column names in the DB match them exactly).  I used `Map(entity => entity.ColorProperty).Custom<ColorType>;` without specifying the columns.

Comment: it's just that NH takes the propertyname as column name if non is specified. It's a fallback you can use but it's not specifying the column names in the ICompositeUserType. `Map(entity => entity.ColorProperty).Coolumns.Add("foo", "bar")` will always result in columns foo, bar

Comment: Based on another post on SO you have to clear the Columns property because it is alreayd populated with the values of PropertyNames.  `Map(entity => entity.ColorProperty).Columns.Clear().Columns.Add("foo", "bar")`

Answer (score 0):

I went with an ICompositeUserType in the end.
Code as follows,

```
public class ColorType : ICompositeUserType
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Get the value of a property
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="component">an instance of class mapped by this "type"</param>
    /// <param name="property"/>
    /// <returns>
    /// the property value
    /// </returns>
    public object GetPropertyValue(object component, int property)
    {
        var color = (Color) component;
        if (property == 0)
        {
            return color.ToArgb();
        }

        return (int) color.ToKnownColor();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set the value of a property
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="component">an instance of class mapped by this "type"</param>
    /// <param name="property"/>
    /// <param name="value">the value to set</param>
    public void SetPropertyValue(object component, int property, object value)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Color is immutable");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Compare two instances of the class mapped by this type for persistence
    ///             "equality", ie. equality of persistent state.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x"/><param name="y"/>
    /// <returns/>
    public new bool Equals(object x, object y)
    {
        return ReferenceEquals(x, y) ||
               x != null && y != null &&
               object.Equals(x, y);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get a hashcode for the instance, consistent with persistence "equality"
    /// </summary>
    public int GetHashCode(object x)
    {
        return x == null
                   ? 0
                   : x.GetHashCode();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieve an instance of the mapped class from a IDataReader. Implementors
    ///             should handle possibility of null values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dr">IDataReader</param>
    /// <param name="names">the column names</param>
    /// <param name="session"/>
    /// <param name="owner">the containing entity</param>
    /// <returns/>
    public object NullSafeGet(IDataReader dr, string[] names,
        ISessionImplementor session, object owner)
    {
        var argb = (int?) NHibernateUtil.Int32.NullSafeGet(dr, names[0]);
        var knownColor = (int?) NHibernateUtil.Int32.NullSafeGet(dr, names[1]);
        return knownColor != null
            ? Color.FromKnownColor((KnownColor) knownColor.Value)
            : Color.FromArgb(argb.Value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Write an instance of the mapped class to a prepared statement.
    ///             Implementors should handle possibility of null values.
    ///             A multi-column type should be written to parameters starting from index.
    ///             If a property is not settable, skip it and don't increment the index.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cmd"/>
    /// <param name="value"/>
    /// <param name="index"/>
    /// <param name="settable"/>
    /// <param name="session"/>
    public void NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, object value, int index,
        bool[] settable, ISessionImplementor session)
    {
        var color = (Color) value;
        if (color.IsKnownColor)
        {
            ((IDataParameter) cmd.Parameters[index]).Value = DBNull.Value;
            ((IDataParameter) cmd.Parameters[index + 1]).Value = (int) color.ToKnownColor();
        }
        else
        {
            ((IDataParameter) cmd.Parameters[index]).Value = color.ToArgb();
            ((IDataParameter) cmd.Parameters[index + 1]).Value = DBNull.Value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return a deep copy of the persistent state, stopping at entities and at collections.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">generally a collection element or entity field</param>
    /// <returns/>
    public object DeepCopy(object value)
    {
        return value;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Transform the object into its cacheable representation.
    ///             At the very least this method should perform a deep copy.
    ///             That may not be enough for some implementations, 
    ///             method should perform a deep copy. That may not be enough for 
    ///             some implementations, however; for example, associations must 
    ///             be cached as identifier values. (optional operation)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">the object to be cached</param>
    /// <param name="session"/>
    /// <returns/>
    public object Disassemble(object value, ISessionImplementor session)
    {
        return value;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reconstruct an object from the cacheable representation.
    ///             At the very least this method should perform a deep copy. (optional operation)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cached">the object to be cached</param>
    /// <param name="session"/>
    /// <param name="owner"/>
    /// <returns/>
    public object Assemble(object cached, ISessionImplementor session, object owner)
    {
        return cached;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// During merge, replace the existing (target) value in the entity we are merging to
    ///             with a new (original) value from the detached entity we are merging. For immutable
    ///             objects, or null values, it is safe to simply return the first parameter. For
    ///             mutable objects, it is safe to return a copy of the first parameter. However, since
    ///             composite user types often define component values, it might make sense to recursively
    ///             replace component values in the target object.
    /// </summary>
    public object Replace(object original, object target, ISessionImplementor session, object owner)
    {
        return original;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the "property names" that may be used in a query.
    /// </summary>
    public string[] PropertyNames { get { return new[] {"Argb", "KnownColor"}; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the corresponding "property types"
    /// </summary>
    public IType[] PropertyTypes
    {
        get
        {
            return new IType[]
                   {
                       NHibernateUtil.Int32, NHibernateUtil.Int32
                   };
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The class returned by NullSafeGet().
    /// </summary>
    public Type ReturnedClass { get { return typeof (Color); } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Are objects of this type mutable?
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsMutable { get { return false; } }
}
```